# Error in my proof that $f \circ f^{-1} \subseteq I_B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I was marked off on this, and am thinking it has to do with the inverse relation not necessarily being a function?

Problem:

For non-empty sets $A$ and $B$, if $f: A\to B$ is a function, then $f \circ f^{-1} \subseteq I_B$

My Proof:

Let $f: A\to B$ and let $(a,b) \in f$. Then $(b,a) \in f^{-1}$. Then $f \circ f^{-1}(b)=f(f^{-1}(b))=f(a)=b$ giving $(b,b)\in f \circ f^{-1}\Rightarrow f \circ f^{-1}\subseteq I_B.$

Comment: What is $I_B$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: Probably the identity relation on $B$ -- that is, $I_B = \{(b,b)\mid b\in B\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know that $f^{-1}$ is a function, you don't know that $f\circ f^{-1}$ is a function either. Therefore you can't use the notation $(f\circ f^{-1})(b)$ as if it necessarily means only a single thing.

Your argument therefore shows at best that if $(a,b)\in f$ then $(b,b)\in f\circ f^{-1}$, but not that all elements of $f\circ f^{-1}$ have this form.

A valid proof might start:

> Let $(b_1,b_2)$ be an arbitary element of $f\circ f^{-1}$. By the definition of $\circ$ this means that there exists an $a$ such that $(b_1,a)\in f^{-1}$ and $(a,b_2)\in f$ ...

Comment: Just to be clear, is $I_B$ the diagonal of $B\times B$? That is, do we have $I_B=\{(b,b):\ b\in B\}$? I think I've always used the notation $\Delta_B$ (or something similar).

Comment: @Clayton: The task at least makes perfect sense if we take $I_B$ to mean that. Note that this set viewed _as a function_ is the identify function $B\to B$, and $I$ is not an uncommon notation for identity mappings and their representations. Consider for example $I$ for the _identity matrix_.

Comment: Yes, that's how I believe my book is using it (A Transition to Advance Mathematics by Smith Eggen and Andre).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thank you for the clarification; it is certainly what I thought but wanted to verify.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @HenningMakholm!